# Из массива объектов JavaScript сохранить объекты с неповторяющимися значениями

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Есть массив объектов JavaScript. Необходимо из этого массива извлечь только те объекты, в которых уникальные значения по ключу VALUE.

То есть из вот такого исходного массива:

```
let citiesArray = [{
  VALUE: "Омск",
  ID: 1,
  CODE: "CITY"
}, {
  VALUE: "Астана",
  ID: 2,
  CODE: "CITY"
}, {
  VALUE: "Астана",
  ID: 22,
  CODE: "CITY"
}, {
  VALUE: "Казань",
  ID: 3441,
  CODE: "CITY"
}, {
  VALUE: "Курган-Тюбе",
  ID: 3,
  CODE: "CITY"
}, {
  VALUE: "Курган-Тюбе",
  ID: 33,
  CODE: "CITY"
}, {
  VALUE: "Курган-Тюбе",
  ID: 333,
  CODE: "CITY"
}, {
  VALUE: "Омск",
  ID: 4,
  CODE: "CITY"
}]
```

должен получиться следующий:

```
[{
  VALUE: "Омск",
  ID: 1,
  CODE: "CITY"
}, {
  VALUE: "Астана",
  ID: 2,
  CODE: "CITY"
}, {
  VALUE: "Казань",
  ID: 3441,
  CODE: "CITY"
}, {
  VALUE: "Курган-Тюбе",
  ID: 3,
  CODE: "CITY"
}]
```

Вопрос - как это сделать красиво на ES6?

Comment: а в чем вопрос? извлеките. Или продемонстрируйте что вы уже пытались сделать и что именно у вас не получилось.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let tmpArray = [];

function itemCheck(item) {
    if (tmpArray.indexOf(item.VALUE) === -1) {
        tmpArray.push(item.VALUE);
        return true
    }
    return false;
}

console.log(citiesArray.filter((item) => itemCheck(item)));
```

Answer (score 6):

нужна [функция reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) и объект, в котором будем помечать было уже значение или нет:

```js
let citiesArray = [{
  VALUE: "Омск",
  ID: 1,
  CODE: "CITY"
}, {
  VALUE: "Астана",
  ID: 2,
  CODE: "CITY"
}, {
  VALUE: "Астана",
  ID: 22,
  CODE: "CITY"
}, {
  VALUE: "Казань",
  ID: 3441,
  CODE: "CITY"
}, {
  VALUE: "Курган-Тюбе",
  ID: 3,
  CODE: "CITY"
}, {
  VALUE: "Курган-Тюбе",
  ID: 33,
  CODE: "CITY"
}, {
  VALUE: "Курган-Тюбе",
  ID: 333,
  CODE: "CITY"
}, {
  VALUE: "Омск",
  ID: 4,
  CODE: "CITY"
}]

let cities = citiesArray.reduce((acc, city) => acc.map[city.VALUE] ? acc : ((acc.map[city.VALUE] = true), acc.cities.push(city), acc), {
  map: {},
  cities: []
}).cities;

console.log(cities);
```

В более читаемом виде:

```js
let citiesArray = [{
  VALUE: "Омск",
  ID: 1,
  CODE: "CITY"
}, {
  VALUE: "Астана",
  ID: 2,
  CODE: "CITY"
}, {
  VALUE: "Астана",
  ID: 22,
  CODE: "CITY"
}, {
  VALUE: "Казань",
  ID: 3441,
  CODE: "CITY"
}, {
  VALUE: "Курган-Тюбе",
  ID: 3,
  CODE: "CITY"
}, {
  VALUE: "Курган-Тюбе",
  ID: 33,
  CODE: "CITY"
}, {
  VALUE: "Курган-Тюбе",
  ID: 333,
  CODE: "CITY"
}, {
  VALUE: "Омск",
  ID: 4,
  CODE: "CITY"
}]

let cities = citiesArray.reduce((acc, city) => {
    if (acc.map[city.VALUE]) // если данный город уже был
      return acc; // ничего не делаем, возвращаем уже собранное

    acc.map[city.VALUE] = true; // помечаем город, как обработанный
    acc.cities.push(city); // добавляем объект в массив городов
    return acc; // возвращаем собранное
  }, {
    map: {}, // здесь будут отмечаться обработанные города
    cities: [] // здесь конечный массив уникальных городов
  })
  .cities; // получаем конечный массив

console.log(cities);
```

Comment: Вот этот фарш из буковок, скобочек и знаков препинания не имеет ничего общего ни с красотой ни с читаемостью. От меня минус за машинно-ориентированный код.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, так лучше?

Comment: Да, так это хотя бы можно читать :)

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, да чего-то не получается красиво, через Set хотел, а там два прохода почти тогда